# Typescript - How to narrow generic mapped types in a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, mapped-types, type-narrowing

I have 3 user types as declared below

```
declare enum UserType {
    Admin = "Admin",
    Tester = "Tester",
    Customer = "Customer",
}

type AdminParams = { ... }
class Admin {
    constructor(parameters: AdminParams) {}
}

type TesterParams = { ... }
class Tester {
    constructor(parameters: TesterParams) {}
}

type CustomerParams = { ... }
class Customer {
    constructor(parameters: CustomerParams) {}
}
```

And I have UserFactory class which generates user instance based on given type

```
// Params based on user Type
type UserTypeParamsMap = {
    [UserType.Admin]: AdminParams;
    [UserType.Tester]: TesterParams;
    [UserType.Customer]: CustomerParams;
};
type UserParam<T extends keyof UserTypeParamsMap> = UserTypeParamsMap[T];

// Class based on user type
type UserTypeInstanceMap = {
    [UserType.Admin]: Admin;
    [UserType.Tester]: Tester;
    [UserType.Customer]: Customer;
};
type UserInstance<T extends keyof UserTypeInstanceMap> = UserTypeInstanceMap[T];

// Factory
export class UserFactory {
    public static createNew = async <T extends keyof UserTypeParamsMap>(userType: T, params: UserParam<T>): Promise<UserInstance<T>> => {
        ...
    }
}
```

Function signature is correct when I input different type of users
[image: function_user_type_admin]
[image: function_user_type_tester]

But in the function it can not narrow params, whenever I check it in if statement
[image]

How can I narrow it to be specific mapped type using given `userType`?

Typescript version: 4.6.3

Expected: `params` to be narrowed to specific type

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEIB2BXAtvAqgZxDAKgJ4AOCA3gLABQ8t8AgsGgJZLwC88ARIy0lwBpqdePhDYALng7cxkvIOF0AwikkB7NNM5dVGrTEVUAvtWoSSCXqwAKsKGmwyy8bJpDWkNmOtIwLAFyuEjCsAObwplSQUNhOnvCUNHRg6kiSMChgEuowABTE9lpSMNhBnnYwDtgAlIlRUeaWouIlldXOru5ybT5%20gcGhSBFRMXEt8jCJSrSp6SFZOfmFVcV4ZRNtRbX11I1UFqTwejkG7Y6dblon7jDevngDGeGR1GNONwbTybNpGYu5ApFEAlDafPDnHZkBpmKgAejh8Eh8AARrEQMB4Gl4GppERSE0jjg8PiQJCALJQYjOGbwADaxIIlgAdJ4ALrlJi2bYAblpDNwTNIzJ6eA5mwhvP5jNJzPBMHF8shfJMKsOCEZ5wAPPhEAAPKRIYBOADWIEI6gAZlhBaSKVSAHwyGWWe3EOn4Nkq6gI47QcZo3CY7G4qbqwka22WACS8ygSDAIEp1M4SREApJLPZnL4KvTLuFooVQSLeboGaFIDlalOYqC8pVxjVzUZsck8cTOv1huN8DNFutBZAbYkHaTjudUdII7HyY9XthvoAYlBsrlCNQQHriLkJPB3ja8Cu1zBCN8RMQUCiIMwwMEoBJb-u4A%20QAA5EAAdxksUICfgXZbj2prmlah6Vm6Dp5KGpIlgI8ArNUQSakUOoOjUQT3CwuBaq2cYJiAaFOuwTppiIdDMNa0FTgg7CcEOrJckgNRkeR5GIY4ZZsSIcASCgMBsEgX4MExeRkFcHhMfc-SEEEXBSJIIl8Fwxg1LSIhRNx8CUdRmZHHR4GykWLHqdxHHYFxWnwLx-GCcJRZiRJRbSY8sncApe5Fipak-ORmncTpMHNAZDHyiZvlaeZllaTZAnwEJ37yo57hKn0rlyR5xw1rc3mmbQ-lsRIAAWPjfgAojAPj5FwmBCWA27gFImKhvA6pcD5Gl7IuABUxwAPIACJlfAS4AEp9eSDBvvA0bkvQADiw3dXCQA)

Comment: you could use a typeguard

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NVayqw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: my suggestion is to use kinda cast function:
`function castUserParams<T extends (keyof ...)>(type: T, value: uknown): UserTypeParamsMap[T] { return value; }` but use it carefully, only after runtime checks. That is just to shut up TS when its not smart enough.